# Match within string based on 1st chars of 3 consecutive (qualifying) words

Tags: php, regex

I have a blob of text, like so:

> with an Angel of Victory, across from the Plaza Hotel, on Fifty-ninth
>   Street. I had promised to alert the skeptical Harrison to the
>   work’s virtues, but we found that it is now hidden in a huge
>   beige box, for a restoration & site. She was thrilled.

I'm trying to form a regex that will allow me to search (and replace) against this text, where there is a match against the first letter (case-insensitive and alphabetical) of three consecutive words.

**For example:** Lets say I have these 3 characters: `v`, `a`, and `f`

Applying the *magical* regex against the example; it would return `Victory, across from`

Further examples:

- `s i h` would match against `Street. I had`
- `s w t` would match against `She was thrilled`
- `t w v` would match against `the work&rsquo;s virtues`
- `a r s` would match against `a restoration &amp; site`

That fourth example may prove too complex, as it essentially needs to ignore words that don't begin with a alphabetical character, but do include them in any result.

Having the match returned, I plan to use that to replace text within the larger example.

*I'm also open to non-regex solutions*.

Comment: explode on space to get words in array, loop it to get first letters ...

Comment: @Dagon No, that won't work (tried it). It ignores the fact that text contains commas etc, and that I need to ignore words that don't start with alphabetical char

Comment: it could be made to work - but this is crazy homework - so im leaving you to it

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$content = 'with an Angel of Victory, across from the Plaza Hotel, on Fifty-ninth Street. I had promised to alert the skeptical Harrison to the work’s virtues, but we found that it is now hidden in a huge beige box, for a restoration & site. She was thrilled.';

$characters = ['v', 'a', 'f'];
$patterns = [];

foreach ($characters as $character) {
    $patterns[] = sprintf('(%s[^\s]*)', preg_quote($character));
}

$regex = sprintf('~\b%s\b~i', implode('\s', $patterns));

preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. Here you end up with an express such as

```
\b        #word boundary
(v[^\s]*) #match first occurance of v until a space.
\s        #space
(a[^\s]*) #match first occurance of a until a space.
\s        #space
(f[^\s]*) #match first occurance of f until a space.
\b        #word boundary
```

Which should give you something like

```
(
    [0] => Victory, across from
    [1] => Victory,
    [2] => across
    [3] => from
)
```

4th scenario regex: (I will leave it to you to decompose this)

```
~\b(a[^\s]*)\s(&[a-z]+;\s*)?(r[^\s]*)\s(&[a-z]+;\s*)?(s[^\s]*)\s(&[a-z]+;\s*)?
```

Comment: For your 4th scenario, I would consider pre-processing. Didn't realize this was a requirement when I wrote the regex and I have to run. As you noted, non-regex solutions often are combined with pre-processing. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. The big issue is matching it back to the original later on. I'll dig into it more. T